# QML: Custom cursor

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

Is there any way to have custom cursor in application. I am not meaning when mouse enters some area, but when application is launched. 
Instead of default cursor there is my cursor image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not from QML. I imagine that if there were a way, it would be exposed through the [Qt.application](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#application-prop) type. You can [do it from C++](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#setOverrideCursor) to achieve the same result though:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    app.setOverrideCursor(Qt::CrossCursor);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));

    return app.exec();
}
```